# usage of while and when and their interchangeability

Tags: grammar

I'd like to know whether 'when' and 'while' are interchangeable:

1. I was cooking when he came in.
2. I was cooking while he came in.
3. He came in while I was cooking.
4. The phone always rings when I am cooking.
5. The phone always rings while I am cooking.
6. The phone rang while I was cooking.
7. The phone rang when I was cooking.

1, 3, 4, and 6 are correct, aren't they? 2 and 7 seem downright incorrect. What about 5?

Comment: The only "really unlikely" one is #2, but even that would be credible if for some reason he *took a long time* to come in.

Comment: Please visit our sister site [ell.se]

Answer (score 2):

They are all correct, IMO. And none are exactly interchangeable, as there are different connotations.  But if you do not care about those nuances then these groups are pretty much interchangeable:

- #1, #2, and #3
- #4 and #5
- #6 and #7

*While* in these contexts makes clear that you are talking about a period of time, a duration.

*When* often means a single moment in time, instead of a duration.  But it is ambiguous, which is why some of the above sentences with *when* are correct even though the listener will likely understand the word to mean a duration. This is the case for #4 and #7, for example.

#2 is correct, but it refers to the period of time during which he came in.  Normally that is short, but it is possible that several events significant to the story took place during this period, etc.

#5 and #4 mean pretty much the same thing.  The *when* of #4 must be understood as the period of time that I cook; it does not refer to the moment when the phone rings, except indirectly, as occuring during the cooking period.  The period of time that the phone rings is not referenced here at all: The ringing is taken as a single event (a moment, or a period of indefinite and insignificant duration here). And the timing of that event is not referenced in the sentence, except to say that it occurs sometime during the period of cooking.